# Set Jquery Mobile ViewPort Manually to reset every page to default size

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have created a mobile application using Jquery Mobile and I want to manually set values to viewport for each page. How this can be done.

Motive: Client is using website in mobile and when hi zooms page with fingers and If he goes to another page the zoom remains same. He wants if he browse other page it will open as default size.

Thanks in advance